# Is this the correct way to analyze games before checking with engine?

Tags: analysis

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 {0} c6 {0} 2. d4 {19} d5 {0} 3. e5 {1} Bf5 {0} 4. Nf3 {1} e6 {0} 5. Be2 {
20} Nd7 {0} 6. O-O {4} Bg6 {0} 7. Nbd2 {53} Nh6 {0} 8. c3 {4} Nf5 {0} 9. Bd3 {
24} Ne3 {0} 10. fxe3 {7} Bxd3 {0} 11. Rf2 {7} Nb6 {0} 12. Ne1 {3 Should'nt
have bothered to take his bad bishop maybe Nd2-f1-g3 was better} Bg6 {0} 13. b3
{7 did'nt wanted his knight to come at c4} Be7 {0} 14. Qf3 {6 i thought maybe
threatening mate} f6 {0} 15. Nf1 {13} Qd7 {0} 16. Ng3 {1} Rf8 {0} 17. Qe2 {8}
fxe5 {0} 18. Rxf8+ {2} Bxf8 {0} 19. Bd2 {6} e4 {0} 20. Nc2 {3} Be7 {0} 21. Rf1
{1} a5 {0} 22. Nh5 {15} O-O-O {0} 23. Nxg7 {2} Kb8 {0} 24. Nh5 {39} Rh8 {0} 25.
Nf4 {2} Bg5 {0} 26. Nxg6 {2 should've not taken his bad bishop,maybe Bd2-e1-g3
was better} hxg6 {0} 27. c4 {3} Qd6 {0} 28. g3 {6} e5 {0} 29. Bxa5 {3} Nc8 {0}
30. Rf7 {19 rook on 7th,maybe Qf2-f7 was even better} b6 {0} 31. Nb4 {19} exd4
{0} 32. Na6+ {8} Ka8 {0} 33. Bxb6 {21} Bxe3+ {0} 34. Kh1 {4} Nxb6 {0} 35. Qg4 {
4} (35. Nc7+ Kb8 36. Na6+ Ka8) 35... Qa3 {0} 36. Nc7+ {11} Kb8 {0} 37. c5 {13}
Qc1+ {0} 38. Kg2 {2} Qg1# {0} 0-1
```

**I am new to analyzing games,is this the right way before checking on engine or am I missing something?(I am playing white)**

Comment: Move 12: Just because the bishop is on the same color as Black's pawns, does not mean the bishop is bad (some might still call it that, but it does not mean it is worthless). It is outside of the pawn chain and a very active piece for Black. On move 26 it is what one would call a bad bishop, as it is blocked in by he pawns.

Comment: You should also annotate good ideas by your opponent, what you don't understand or when you think they went wrong, not only your side.

Comment: Look at first moves first. At 7.Nbd2 you have knight blocking the bishop development. Is that your intention to get into passive defense right away? You are White who has Alpha - the tempo advantage. You want to get as much win percent as possible from that bonus. And you play passive move

Answer (score 4):

Works for me. Review that game with a person, someone who'll tell you why you should do or not do things, for whom one-millionth of a pawn isn't an issue. For instance, getting the bishop to d3 in one step instead of two.  4. Nf3 and 5. Be2 are grandmasterly, not as simple.